# how to group based on unique array of object and getting unique element and element of string values

Tags: javascript

i have an array of object like below. and i want to reconstruct it based on its category. and convert all subcategory into a string.

```
 var main = [{
   "id": "1",
   "category": "Staples",
   "sub_category": "Dals & Pulses"
 }, {
   "id": "2",
   "category": "Staples",
   "sub_category": "Ghee & Oils"
 }, {
   "id": "3",
   "category": "Staples",
   "sub_category": "Atta & Flours"
 }, {
   "id": "4",
   "category": "Staples",
   "sub_category": "Masalas & Spices"
 }, {
   "id": "5",
   "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
   "sub_category": "Biscuits"
 }, {
   "id": "6",
   "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
   "sub_category": "Chips"
 }, {
   "id": "7",
   "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
   "sub_category": "Namkeen & Snacks"
 }, {
   "id": "8",
   "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
   "sub_category": "Tea"
 }]
```

know i need to get result like below, with 2 elements only, category and a subcategory string separated by comma as below.

```
> EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

 var result = [
{ 
   category: 'Staples',
   sub_cat: 'Dals & Pulses, Ghee & Oils, Atta & Flours, Masalas & Spices' },
{ 
   category: 'Snacks and Beverages',
   sub_cat: 'Biscuits, Chips, Namkeen & Snacks, Tea' 
}],
```

the sub category is a string value here.

i did somthing like this

```
categories.map(key => {
                            sub_category.map(element => {
                                if (key.category == element.category) {
                                    console.log(key.category);
                                    console.log(element.sub_category);
                                }
                            });
                        });
```

the output was

```
JS: Staples
JS: Dals & Pulses
JS: Staples
JS: Ghee & Oils
JS: Staples
JS: Atta & Flours
JS: Staples
JS: Masalas & Spices
JS: Snacks and Beverages
JS: Biscuits
JS: Snacks and Beverages
JS: Chips
JS: Snacks and Beverages
JS: Namkeen & Snacks
JS: Snacks and Beverages
JS: Tea
JS: Snacks and Beverages
JS: Coffe
```

I'm Really confused on how to construct a new array with about about. if i try to push it in new array. i don't want category to add multiple times, if i try to push sub category into array i need to convert it to a string before push. but how any ideas is thankfulll

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: 'var result =  ' --- >  look here in the code

Comment: the same question is posted by this(https://stackoverflow.com/users/11404646/modi) user and deleted by him some minutes ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest approach is to collect the data with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and render the wanted result by taking key and values.

It uses, in order of logic,

- reducing the data with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), where a `Map` acts as accumulator and return value,
- this `Map` is handed over to [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), where an [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Built-in_iterables) is used for converting to an array with or without a further mapping function, which is given, here with
- a callback which takes a key/value pair and returns an object by taking [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var data = [{ id: "1", category: "Staples", sub_category: "Dals & Pulses" }, { id: "2", category: "Staples", sub_category: "Ghee & Oils" }, { id: "3", category: "Staples", sub_category: "Atta & Flours" }, { id: "4", category: "Staples", sub_category: "Masalas & Spices" }, { id: "5", category: "Snacks and Beverages", sub_category: "Biscuits" }, { id: "6", category: "Snacks and Beverages", sub_category: "Chips" }, { id: "7", category: "Snacks and Beverages", sub_category: "Namkeen & Snacks" }, { id: "8", category: "Snacks and Beverages", sub_category: "Tea" }],
    result = Array.from(
        data.reduce((m, { category, sub_category }) => m.set(category, [...(m.get(category) || []), sub_category]), new Map),
        ([category, sub_category]) => ({ category, sub_cat: sub_category.join(', ') })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A simplified version of above with an object as hash table for same categories.

```js
var data = [{ id: "1", category: "Staples", sub_category: "Dals & Pulses" }, { id: "2", category: "Staples", sub_category: "Ghee & Oils" }, { id: "3", category: "Staples", sub_category: "Atta & Flours" }, { id: "4", category: "Staples", sub_category: "Masalas & Spices" }, { id: "5", category: "Snacks and Beverages", sub_category: "Biscuits" }, { id: "6", category: "Snacks and Beverages", sub_category: "Chips" }, { id: "7", category: "Snacks and Beverages", sub_category: "Namkeen & Snacks" }, { id: "8", category: "Snacks and Beverages", sub_category: "Tea" }],
    hash = {},
    item,
    i
    result = [];

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    item = data[i];
    if (!hash[item.category]) {
        hash[item.category] = { category: item.category, sub_cat: item.sub_category };
        result.push(hash[item.category]);
        continue;
    }
    hash[item.category].sub_cat += ', ' + item.sub_category;
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it's really easy and good. but i didn't understand the code. can you give some useful tutorial links to understand your answer. I'm a fresher.

Comment: you could follow the links above and start with `reduce`. this is an important feature to fold an array to a single value.

Comment: i read it, but still didn't understand your logic, it's too complicated and very simple. thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. I have looped the `main` array and pushed the first element in to `result` array then I pushed the first occurence of a category to `availableCat` array also. and then I identified the next same category using `availableCat` arry and then I concatenate the data.

```js
var main = [{
   "id": "1",
   "category": "Staples",
   "sub_category": "Dals & Pulses"
 }, {
   "id": "2",
   "category": "Staples",
   "sub_category": "Ghee & Oils"
 }, {
   "id": "3",
   "category": "Staples",
   "sub_category": "Atta & Flours"
 }, {
   "id": "4",
   "category": "Staples",
   "sub_category": "Masalas & Spices"
 }, {
   "id": "5",
   "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
   "sub_category": "Biscuits"
 }, {
   "id": "6",
   "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
   "sub_category": "Chips"
 }, {
   "id": "7",
   "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
   "sub_category": "Namkeen & Snacks"
 }, {
   "id": "8",
   "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
   "sub_category": "Tea"
 }]

var result=[];
var availableCat = [];
main.forEach(function(data){
  if(availableCat.indexOf(data.category) >= 0){
    result.forEach(function(cnt){
      if(cnt.category == data.category){
        cnt.sub_cat += ', '+ data.sub_category
      }
    })
  }
  else {
    availableCat.push(data.category);
    var item = {"category" : data.category, "sub_cat" : data.sub_category}
    result.push(item);
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another way to do this. Using lodash and Array.reduce

```
var _ = require('lodash')
var main = [{
    "id": "1",
    "category": "Staples",
    "sub_category": "Dals & Pulses"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "category": "Staples",
    "sub_category": "Ghee & Oils"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "category": "Staples",
    "sub_category": "Atta & Flours"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "category": "Staples",
    "sub_category": "Masalas & Spices"
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
    "sub_category": "Biscuits"
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
    "sub_category": "Chips"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
    "sub_category": "Namkeen & Snacks"
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
    "sub_category": "Tea"
}]

var grouped = _.groupBy(main,'category')

var result = Object.keys(grouped).map(key => {
    return {
        category: key,
        sub_category: grouped[key].reduce((acc, curr) => acc = acc + curr.sub_category + ', ','')
    }
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first group the array of objects by the `category` property using [`Array#prototype#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) after doing that join the subcategories by using [`Array#prototype#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
const main = [
 {
   "id": "1",
   "category": "Staples",
   "sub_category": "Dals & Pulses"
 }, {
   "id": "2",
   "category": "Staples",
   "sub_category": "Ghee & Oils"
 }, {
   "id": "3",
   "category": "Staples",
   "sub_category": "Atta & Flours"
 }, {
   "id": "4",
   "category": "Staples",
   "sub_category": "Masalas & Spices"
 }, {
   "id": "5",
   "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
   "sub_category": "Biscuits"
 }, {
   "id": "6",
   "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
   "sub_category": "Chips"
 }, {
   "id": "7",
   "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
   "sub_category": "Namkeen & Snacks"
 }, {
   "id": "8",
   "category": "Snacks and Beverages",
   "sub_category": "Tea"
 }
];


const result = Object.values(main.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
 const { category, sub_category } = curr;
    if (!acc[category]) {
     acc[category] = {
   category: category,
   sub_category: [ sub_category ]
  };
 }
 else {
     acc[category].sub_category.push(sub_category);
 }
 
 return acc;
}, {}))
.map(x => {
 const { sub_category, ...rest } = x;
 return {
  ...rest,
  sub_category: sub_category.join(', ')
 };
});

console.log(result);
```